# Task parameter scope on gRPC server

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, grpc, grpc-c#

I have a gRPC server Task that gets called from clients. The request parameter is scoped in the Task and i dont know how to retrieve it and use it in other classes.
printing "currentRequest" outside of the task returns nothing.
Thank you so much for your help.

```
public class LoggingImpl : Logging.LoggingBase
{
    private Server server;
    RequestInfo currentRequest;
    public ClientController controller;

    public override Task<LoggingResponse> LoggingMCM(RequestInfo request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        currentRequest = request;
        Console.Log(currentRequest);
        return Task.FromResult(new LoggingResponse { Result = "this is a reply from Unity Server" });
    }

    public void GetRequestInfo()
    {
        Console.Log(currentRequest);
    }


    public void StartServer()
    {
        server = new Server
        {
            Services = { Logging.BindService(new LoggingImpl()) },
            Ports = { new ServerPort("127.0.0.1", 50010, ServerCredentials.Insecure) }

        };
        server.Start();
    }
}
```

I was expecting the currentRequest to be usable outside of the Taks scope. How would one use the request info on the main thread and other classes?

Answer (score 0):

Since [gRPC services are registered as transient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/clientfactory?view=aspnetcore-6.0#register-grpc-clients) (at least if they are registered the standard way), a new instance of your class *LogginImpl* will be created for each gRPC call to the service, that only exists during the handling of the call and will then be removed by the GC, therefore the *currentRequest* is almost always *null*.

Making the request static could result in the behaviour you expect, since it will not be re-instantiated with each call (in line 4):

```csharp
private static RequestInfo currentRequest;
```

Keep in mind, if you want to log a (string) message from the request, you still have to extract the message from the request (since you pass the whole object to the Console in the *GetRequestInfo()* method)